# Add a new field based on others to a document every time it's fetched

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

My Question schema looks like this:

```js
const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: String,
    options: [{
        content: String,
        correct: Boolean
    }]
});
```

I also have a Test schema, where I refer to Question:

```js
const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // ... 
    questions: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Question"
    }]
})
```

When I fetch Questions (using `find()`, `findOne()` or `Test.find().populate("questions")`) I'd like to add to the document a new boolean field `multiple` based to on how many `options` have `correct === true`. Expected output:

```js
{
    _id: "...",
    _v: 1,
    content: "What is a capital of Slovenia?"
    options: [
        {
            content: "Bled",
            correct: false
        },
        {
            content: "Ljubljana",
            correct: true
        }
    ],
    multiple: false
}
```

Is it possible to use some kind of a function which is called everytime I query Question and adds a new field to a fetched object or do I have to store `multiple` field permanently in Mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your needs there are a couple of approaches here.

## Mongoose Virtual Field

The most direct should be since you are using mongoose would be to add a [`virtual`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) field to the schema which basically calculates it's value when it is accessed. You don't specify your logic in the question, but presuming something like "more than one `true`" means that `multiple` is `true` then you would do something like this:

```
const questionSchema = new Schema({
  content: String,
  options: [{
    content: String,
    correct: Boolean
  }]
},
{
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  toObject: { virtuals: true }
});

questionSchema.virtual('multiple').get(function() {
  return this.options.filter(e => e.correct).length > 1;
});
```

That's a basic "getter" which simply looks at the array content and returns if the number of `true` elements for the `correct` property are more than one within the array content. It can really be whatever logic you want in the function. Note the use of `function()` and not `() =>` since "arrow functions" have a different scope of `this` and that is important to mongoose to determine the current instance value at the time of evaluation.

The `toJSON` and `toObject` options in the schema definition are *optional*, but basically their point is that you can access the "virtual" property directly ( i.e `question.multiple === false` ) but something like `console.log(question)` does NOT show the `virtual` properties unless that definition is added with those options.

### MongoDB Projection

Another option is to just have MongoDB do the work to return the modified document from the server in results. This is done using the aggregation framework, which is basically the tool for any "result manipulation".

Here as an example we implement the same logic as presented in the virtual method, along with using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in the same way a `populate()` would be done. Except of course this is **one** request to the server and not **two** as would be the case with `populate()`, which simply issues a separate query for the "related" data:

```
// Logic in aggregate result
let result = await Test.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Question.collection.name,
    "let": { "questions": "$questions" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$in": [ "$_id", "$$questions" ]
        }
      }},
      { "$addFields": {
        "multiple": {
          "$gt": [
            { "$size": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$options",
                "cond": "$$this.correct"
              }
            }},
            1
          ]
        }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "questions"
  }}
]);
```

Same sort of operations with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) instead of [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) instead of [`Array.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length). Again the main benefit is the "server join" here, so it's possibly better for you to implement the "virtual" logic there rather than on the schema.

Whilst it is *"possible"* to do things like using an `aggregate()` result with mongoose schema and methods, the default behavior is that `aggregate()` returns "plain objects"
 and not the "mongoose document" instances which have the schema methods. You *could* re-cast the results and use schema methods, but that's probably going to mean defining "special" schema and model classes just for specific "aggregation" results, and probably not the most efficient thing to do.

---

Overall which one you implement depends on which suits your application needs the best.

And of course whilst you *"could"* also just store the same data in the MongoDB document instead of calculating each time it's retrieved, then the overhead basically shifts to the time of writing the data, where mostly this would depend on how you write data. For instance if you "add new options" to existing options then you basically need to read the whole document from MongoDB, inspect the content and then decide what to write back for the `multiple` value. So the same logic presented here ( more than one `true` in the array ) has no "atomic" write process that can be done without reading the document data first.

As a working example of these approaches, see the following listing:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const questionSchema = new Schema({
  content: String,
  options: [{
    content: String,
    correct: Boolean
  }]
},
{
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  toObject: { virtuals: true }
});

questionSchema.virtual('multiple').get(function() {
  return this.options.filter(e => e.correct).length > 1;
});

const testSchema = new Schema({
  questions: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Question'
  }]
});


const Question = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);
const Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));


(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.deleteMany())
    );

    // Insert some data

    let questions = await Question.insertMany([
      {
        "content": "What is the a capital of Slovenia?",
        "options": [
          { "content": "Bled", "correct": false },
          { "content": "Ljubljana", "correct": true }
        ]
      },
      {
        "content": "Who are the most excellent people?",
        "options": [
          { "content": "Bill", "correct": true },
          { "content": "Ted", "correct": true },
          { "content": "Evil Duke", "correct": false }
        ]
      }
    ]);

    await Test.create({ questions })


    // Just the questions
    let qresults = await Question.find();
    log(qresults);

    // Test with populated questions
    let test = await Test.findOne().populate('questions');
    log(test);

    // Logic in aggregate result
    let result = await Test.aggregate([
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Question.collection.name,
        "let": { "questions": "$questions" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [ "$_id", "$$questions" ]
            }
          }},
          { "$addFields": {
            "multiple": {
              "$gt": [
                { "$size": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$options",
                    "cond": "$$this.correct"
                  }
                }},
                1
              ]
            }
          }}
        ],
        "as": "questions"
      }}
    ]);

    log(result);


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect()
  }

})()
```

And it's output:

```
Mongoose: questions.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: tests.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: questions.insertMany([ { _id: 5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f728, content: 'What is the a capital of Slovenia?', options: [ { _id: 5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72a, content: 'Bled', correct: false }, { _id: 5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f729, content: 'Ljubljana', correct: true } ], __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72b, content: 'Who are the most excellent people?', options: [ { _id: 5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72e, content: 'Bill', correct: true }, { _id: 5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72d, content: 'Ted', correct: true }, { _id: 5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72c, content: 'Evil Duke', correct: false } ], __v: 0 } ], {})
Mongoose: tests.insertOne({ questions: [ ObjectId("5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f728"), ObjectId("5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72b") ], _id: ObjectId("5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72f"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: questions.find({}, { projection: {} })
[
  {
    "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f728",
    "content": "What is the a capital of Slovenia?",
    "options": [
      {
        "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72a",
        "content": "Bled",
        "correct": false
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f729",
        "content": "Ljubljana",
        "correct": true
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0,
    "multiple": false,
    "id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f728"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72b",
    "content": "Who are the most excellent people?",
    "options": [
      {
        "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72e",
        "content": "Bill",
        "correct": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72d",
        "content": "Ted",
        "correct": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72c",
        "content": "Evil Duke",
        "correct": false
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0,
    "multiple": true,
    "id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72b"
  }
]
Mongoose: tests.findOne({}, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: questions.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f728"), ObjectId("5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72b") ] } }, { projection: {} })
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f728",
      "content": "What is the a capital of Slovenia?",
      "options": [
        {
          "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72a",
          "content": "Bled",
          "correct": false
        },
        {
          "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f729",
          "content": "Ljubljana",
          "correct": true
        }
      ],
      "__v": 0,
      "multiple": false,
      "id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f728"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72b",
      "content": "Who are the most excellent people?",
      "options": [
        {
          "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72e",
          "content": "Bill",
          "correct": true
        },
        {
          "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72d",
          "content": "Ted",
          "correct": true
        },
        {
          "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72c",
          "content": "Evil Duke",
          "correct": false
        }
      ],
      "__v": 0,
      "multiple": true,
      "id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72b"
    }
  ],
  "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72f",
  "__v": 0
}
Mongoose: tests.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'questions', let: { questions: '$questions' }, pipeline: [ { '$match': { '$expr': { '$in': [ '$_id', '$$questions' ] } } }, { '$addFields': { multiple: { '$gt': [ { '$size': { '$filter': { input: '$options', cond: '$$this.correct' } } }, 1 ] } } } ], as: 'questions' } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72f",
    "questions": [
      {
        "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f728",
        "content": "What is the a capital of Slovenia?",
        "options": [
          {
            "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72a",
            "content": "Bled",
            "correct": false
          },
          {
            "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f729",
            "content": "Ljubljana",
            "correct": true
          }
        ],
        "__v": 0,
        "multiple": false
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72b",
        "content": "Who are the most excellent people?",
        "options": [
          {
            "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72e",
            "content": "Bill",
            "correct": true
          },
          {
            "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72d",
            "content": "Ted",
            "correct": true
          },
          {
            "_id": "5cce2f0b83d75c2d1fe6f72c",
            "content": "Evil Duke",
            "correct": false
          }
        ],
        "__v": 0,
        "multiple": true
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```